# How can I trigger the end of ssh?

Tags: shell, ssh

I use a proxy server and change network settings every time.
So I want shell script like

```sh
use_proxy(){
  # change network
  ssh proxy -N
  # revert change
}
```

I tried `trap` command like

```
$ trap "echo 'detected!'" 2
$ ssh proxy -N
```

But "detected!" is not printed when I finish ssh by Ctrl+C.
Is there any problem?

Comment: In bash case, thsutton's answer solved this. 
And I'm using zsh and defining TRAPCHLD didn't work for me.
Can I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a process is interrupted (e.g. from ctrl-c), that process receives `SIGINT`. If you want to know when a child process has changed, trap `SIGCHLD` instead:

```
$ trap "echo int" SIGINT
$ trap "echo child" SIGCHLD
$ /bin/cat
ctrl+c
child
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 
I could do it in bash, but I couldn't in zsh.  
So I usually use zsh and defined TRAPCHLD, but it didn't work.  
http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Functions.html#Special-Functions  
Do you have any ideas?

Comment: @kurarrr I don't use zsh sorry.